# shader uses descriptor slot (expected `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`) but not declared in pipeline layout

Tags: vulkan

the full error

[ VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-layout-00756 ] Object 0: handle = 0xa43473000000002d, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE; Object 1: handle = 0x4b7df1000000002f, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT; | MessageID = 0x45717876 | Set 5 Binding 0 in shader uses descriptor slot (expected `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`) but not declared in pipeline layout The Vulkan spec states: layout must be consistent with all shaders specified in pStages (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.236.0/mac/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-layout-00756)

my vertex-shader -------------------------------

```
layout(location = 0) out vec2 _texcoords;

vec2 positions[4] = vec2[]
(
    vec2( 1.0,  1.0),
    vec2(-1.0,  1.0),
    vec2(-1.0, -1.0),
    vec2( 1.0, -1.0)
);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( positions[ gl_VertexIndex ], 0.0, 1.0 );
    _texcoords = (positions[ gl_VertexIndex ] + 1.0f) * 0.5;
}
```

my fragment-shader -------------------------------

```
layout(set = 5, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D _color_texture[2];
layout(location = 0) out vec4  _out_color;
layout(location = 0) in  vec2  _texcoords;

void main()
{
    _out_color = texture( _color_texture[0], _texcoords );
}
```

now if I create a shader from this shader code the program crashes with the above error. I know my pipeline creation works because it's the same for every other shader. the minute my shader  contains uniform sampler2D my graphics pipeline no longer works. to trouble shoot I print out the infos to see what going on and as you can see.

DESCRIPTOR-SET-LAYOUT: 0x980b0000000002e, set: [5], binding: [0], VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER

PIPELINE-MODULE: 0xb12fb2000000002c
PIPELINE-MODULE: 0xa43473000000002d
PIPELINE-LAYOUT: 0x4b7df1000000002f
PIPELINE: 0xa21a4e0000000030

my descriptor do have an handle and was created with VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, my shader-modules, pipeline-layout, and pipeline do also have and handle. the pipeline is created with a VK_SUCCESS but still generates this validation error. I should note that I am using Molten Vulkan on MacOS 17.

break point stepping through the program to see if my descriptors and pipeline are begin created properly and with the correct types parameters. which checks out. printing out infos to show what's going on. When I set my set the set index to 0 like so

my fragment-shader -------------------------------

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D _color_texture[2];
layout(location = 0) out vec4  _out_color;
layout(location = 0) in  vec2  _texcoords;

void main()
{
    _out_color = texture( _color_texture[0], _texcoords );
}
```

it runs ok with out any errors. can anyone tell me what's going on here.

Comment: Update your SDK, so we can be sure that we are addressing current state of matters. 236 is year old. And that VUID does not even seem to exist in current specification.